# Forcing "/" on home page (index page)?

Tags: canonical-link

I am using this code for my redirects on my `.htaccess` file:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^allvalleytransportation.com [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.allvalleytransportation.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

 RewriteEngine On 
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 # Force trailing slash
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ 
   RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
 </IfModule>
```

It appears to resolve the "/" on my subpages, however my index page does not force a trailing slash.

If I type in `allvalleytransportation.com` and copy the URL from the browser it generates this:

https://www.allvalleytransportation.com/

This is correct, however on the browser window itself, it appears without the trailing slash. Please see screenshot below. Is this something to be concerned about or is this normal?

Here is a conversation I had with YOAST that may help explain further.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/canonical-issue-15/#post-15921609

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An absolute URL with **no** path is the same as one with the path `/`.

If you type `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/` into a browser's address bar, it will ask for `/`.

The difference is only in what is displayed in the browser's address bar.

(The same applies to any other client, only it might not have a visible address bar).

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. So on a "canonical level", everything is okay?

Comment: Yes, everything is OK for canonical whether or not the trailing slash for the home page is shown in the browser or not.  As Quentin says, it is only a display issue, it is **always** sent with the HTTP request for the home page.  The HTTP protocol treats it differently than trailing slashes on sub-directories.  There is no way to add or remove a trailing slash for the home page using rewrite rules (or any other server side technology.)